# How to postpone a delayed job in Hangfire using SQL script

Tags: sql-server, hangfire, hangfire-sql

We have been using Hangfire v.7 with SQL Server for a long time and have a lot of delayed jobs. I want to find those scheduled to run in a specific period (e.g. from 2030-01-01T01:00:00 to 2030-01-01T03:00:00) and postpone them for N hours. I assume there are some columns in the Hangfire database that specify the execution time of each job. Is it valid? How can I change the execution time of delayed jobs via a SQL script?

Comment: Wait, SQL Server v.7?  As in v7.0 released in 1998?

Comment: My fault, I meant Hangfire v.7. I've edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the Hangfire source code and followed the process starting from `BackgroundJob.Schedule`, which is the API method for creating a new delayed job, until the changes it commits to the DB. This is the DB schema:

[image: DB Schema]

Every delayed job has a record in the `[Job]` table and its execution data is saved in the `[State]` table. An unexecuted scheduled job has a state record like this:
[image: State record]

The `[Data]` column has scheduling details in JSON format. The value of `EnqueueAt` is when the job is supposed to start execution in the UNIX time stamp. For SQL Server v.16 or higher a script like this can be useful:

```
UPDATE [State] 
SET JSON_MODIFY([Data], '$.EnqueueAt', '0000000000000'/*put your time stamp here*/)
WHERE condition
```